# Session persistence on nginx after configuration reload

Tags: nginx

Will nginx continue to respect session persistence even after a configuration reload, or will it consider all requests as new sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the approach, seems some of the information from previous requests can be stored on the client to determine the session persistence...

> Subsequent requests from the client include the cookie value and NGINX Plus uses it to route the request to the same upstream server

Or using stick routes

> With this method, NGINX Plus searches the parameters to the sticky route directive ($var1, $var2, and so on) and compares the first non-empty value to the route value for each server. If there’s a match, NGINX Plus chooses the matching server; otherwise, it uses the configured load-balancing algorithm to decide where to route the request.

Either would persist if the config was reloaded in between requests.

https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/